# Passing data with String Request volley is not working in Android Kotlin

Tags: php, android, kotlin, android-volley

So I tried to connect my android app with the database that I stored in Phpmyadmin. I am using Volley since a lot of people recommend this. I followed some tutorials and finally got this code:

```
lateinit var etLoginEmail : EditText
lateinit var etLoginPass : EditText
lateinit var btnLog_in : Button

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9){
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build())
    }
     etLoginEmail = findViewById(R.id.etLoginEmail) as EditText
     etLoginPass = findViewById(R.id.etLoginPass) as EditText
    btnLog_in = findViewById(R.id.btnLog_in) as Button

    btnLog_in.setOnClickListener {
        if (etLoginEmail?.text.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            etLoginEmail?.error = "Email must be filled"
        } else if (etLoginPass?.text.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            etLoginPass?.error = "Password must be filled"
        } else{            
            doLogin(etLoginEmail.text.toString(), etLoginPass.text.toString())
            }
        }
    }
 fun doLogin(userEmail: String, userPass: String){
    val stringRequest = object : StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://localhost/my_app/login.php",
        Response.Listener<String> { response ->
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            try {
                val obj = JSONObject(response)
                    startActivity(Intent(this, TabbedHome::class.java))
                    finish()
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            } catch (e: JSONException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        },
        object : Response.ErrorListener {
            override fun onErrorResponse(volleyError: VolleyError) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, volleyError.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }) {
        @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
        override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
            val params = HashMap<String, String>()
            params.put("user_email", userEmail)
            params.put("user_pass", userPass)
            return params
        }
    }
    VolleySingleton.instance?.addToRequestQueue(stringRequest)
}
```

I imported these Volley tools on my Login.kt class

```
import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.VolleyError
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
import com.android.volley.Response
```

However, the volley code is not working when I run the app on my device. I also don't get any error in the logcat. When I clicked the button, it didn't do anything. Not even showing any error message. Only some error like this `E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only`

I tried my php code on postman and it works like a champ. This is my php code:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'connection.php';
 if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){         
    $user_email = $_POST["user_email"];
    $user_pass = $_POST['user_pass']; 

}
     if ((empty($user_email)) || (empty($user_pass))) { 
        $response->success = 0;
        $response->message = "Field must be filled"; 
        die(json_encode($response));
     }
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tb_user WHERE user_email='$user_email'");
     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
     $result = $mysqli->query($row);
        $followingdata = $result->fetch_assoc();
     $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id']; 
 if (password_verify($user_pass, $row['user_pass'])) {
     if (!empty($row)){
        $response = new usr();
        $response->success = 1;
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $_POST['user_id'];
        $response->message = "Welcome ".$row['user_name'];
        $response->user_id = $row['user_id'];
        $response->user_name = $row['user_name'];
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
        $user_id = $row['user_id'];
        die(json_encode($response));
     }
} else { 

            $response->success = 0;
            $response->message = "Email or pass is in correct";
            die(json_encode($response));
         } 
     mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I tried to search some problems that looks like mine all over the Internet but still couldn't find the answer to my problem. I also already put this code on my AndroidManifest.xml below the `<manifest>` tag and right before the `<application>` tag.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

And this is the dependency that I imported.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.0.0"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1"
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

I imported more than 1 dependencies to pass the data because I tried it all and nothing has worked...

Can someone please tell me what did I do wrong? Any help will be really appreciated. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @Dharman thanks for the warning. I'll try to change it to password hash.

Comment: Thank you so much @Dharman. I already changed it to password hash. But I still couldn't find the solution to my problem. The problem here is my android app can't connect to the database even when my Volley code is not showing any error.

Comment: If you have updated your PHP code and still facing issues then you should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57002029/edit) your question to show the updated code.

Comment: Do accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

At `php side` you are decoding `json` but at `android side` you are passing parameters as `form-data`.

So, either change `php-side` code to receive `form-data` or pass data in raw-form (as JSON) at Android side.

To receive form-data with `POST` request try below_code:

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){         
    $user_email = $_POST["user_email"];
    $user_pass = $_POST['user_pass']; 
}
```

With above code you can get posted `form-data` at `PHP`.Now you can do whatever you want with the data.

Comment: Thank you so much, I just noticed that. But could you please show me how to receive `form-data` in the php-side? I'm actually new to back-end so I don't really know about php.